# How to disable Bloodhound's ajax 'global' flag (Typeahead.js)

Tags: javascript, typeahead.js, bloodhound

I've seen people configure the AJAX request `Bloodhound` is performing in `typeahead.js` by including an `ajax` object like this on their constructor:

```
var locsData = new Bloodhound({
  datumTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.obj.whitespace("name"),
  queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
  remote: {
    url: "/locations/search.json?q=%QUERY",
    ajax: {
      beforeSend: function(xhr, settings) {
        // maybe the 'if' is not necessary, but just to be sure...
        if ($(document.activeElement).typeahead != null) {
          $(document.activeElement).addClass('loading-text');
        }
      },
      complete: function(xhr, status) {
        if ($(document.activeElement).typeahead != null) {
          $(document.activeElement).removeClass('loading-text');
        }
      }
    }
  },
  limit: 100
});
```

However, I've been taking a look at the sources and found no way to configure ajax that way on latest version (v.0.11.1 at this time). **I need to turn off `ajax` flag `global`** so it doesn't trigger my loading gifs when sending ajax requests to the server but I can't find out how to do it.

Tried this both ways. You'll notice that I'm using `struts2` by the way I specified the URLs:

```
var engine = new Bloodhound({
            remote: {
                url: '<s:url value="%{#typeaheadHwsnUrl}"/>'+'%QUERY%',
                wildcard: '%QUERY%',
                ajax: {
                    global: false,
                }
            },
            datumTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace('q'),
            queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace
        });
```

and also, with no luck tried outside of the `remote` object:

```
    var engine = new Bloodhound({
        remote: {
            url: '<s:url value="%{#typeaheadHwsnUrl}"/>'+'%QUERY%',
            wildcard: '%QUERY%',
        },
        datumTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace('q'),
        queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
        ajax: {
            global: false,
        }
```

How can I turn off this `global` flag for `ajax` calls made by `Bloodhound`?

Answer (score 0):

My colleague ran into same scenario this morning and he has done a workaround by using $.ajaxSend() with an if-statement to determine whether the URL needs a loading GIF animation or not.

Hope this helped :)

Comment: I ended up doing something similar, but I'd leave this open for now and see if somehow somebody knows the "right" way to address this issue, thanks for your answer though!